# MySQL Workbench - Error Getting DDL Object (It doesn't exist?)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

The problem started when a table, started not to fetch a single SELECT. It was only a `SELECT * FROM table;` and it started to run and never stopped. After several attempts, all of them failed, and then I tried to drop the table (it has backups), but the **SAME** problem happened.

My last, and failed attempt was to rename the table and then restore a backup table.

I tried to use MySQL Workbench feature to Alter Tables but, Windows error (I use Windows 7 at my job). Windows offered me to "Try to restore the program" and it indicates me it was an "Error Getting DDL Object". Then I checked the tables information, and DDL tab was **empty**.

So.... I don't what to do. Is there a way to change this DDL? Or maybe another way?

Comment: I already tried to add a column too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered, after a long research, that it could be a process which wans't interrupted (somehow).

Then it was only:

```
show processlist;
kill [ID of the running process];
```

And then I was able to drop/alter that table.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error message with a full disk at the server side where MySQL was running. Obviously, MySQL server failed to run correctly.